# RSA Algorithm Question

Tags: cryptography

- Suppose the primes p and q used in the RSA algorithm are consecutive primes (meaning they differ by 2). How would you factor n = pq?
- The ciphertext 10787770728 was encrypted using n = 10993522499 and e = 113. The
  factors p and q of n were chosen so that p - q = 2. Use your method in part (a) to
  decrypt the message

Comment: Taking the square root of $n$ will get you most of the way there for the first part

Comment: $n = pq = (2+q)q = 2q + q^2 \implies q^2 + 2q - n = 0$. Thus, we have
$$
q= \frac{-2 + \sqrt{4 + 4n}}{2}
$$
which gives
$$
q =  {-1 + \sqrt{1 + n}}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Set $n^2-1=10993522499$.
Isolate $n^2$.
$n$ is its positive square root.
Your two factors are $n-1$ and $n+1$.